# constexpr reference to non-const object

Tags: c++, reference, c++14, language-lawyer, constexpr

Is it permitted to declare a non-const reference as `constexpr`? Example code:

```
int x = 1;
constexpr int& r = x;
```

This is accepted by gcc and clang (I tried several current and past versions of both, back to C++11, and all accepted it).  However I think it should not be accepted because C++14 [dcl.constexpr/9] says:

> if a constexpr specifier is used in a reference declaration, every full-
>   expression that appears in its initializer shall be a constant expression

and `x` is not a constant expression.

The language in the latest C++17 draft of [dcl.constexpr] changed and doesn't even mention `constexpr` references explicitly any more, I can't make head nor tail of what it is trying to say about them.

Comment: Who said `x` isn't a constant expression?

Comment: "`x` isn't a core constant expression" {{citation needed}}

Comment: @T.C. [expr.const]/2 "`e` is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of `e` would evaluate one of the following: [...] an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, unless it is applied to [cases that this code doesn't match]"

Comment: `x` is assigned a literal value, shouldn't that be good enough for the compiler to know it is compile-time known?

Comment: How does evaluating the expression `x` necessitate an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on it?

Comment: @T.C. I thought it was implied that it was ... apparently not. So `x` would instead be covered by /2.9 which I'm assuming it is intended to say that an id-expression denoting an object is a constant expression iff it was initialized with a constant expression. Not clear to me whether that sentence means "(a variable) or (data member of reference type)", or "(a variable or data member) of reference type"

Comment: The latter, of course. Before digging into the complicated C++1* rules, remember that this has been always been valid: `int x; template<int&> struct C {}; C<x> c;` Something that can be used as a template argument must be a constant expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `x` has static storage duration, the lvalue expression `x` is a perfectly valid constant expression.

If you use `x` in a context that requires a prvalue, which causes the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to be applied to it, then the resulting prvalue expression - call it `TO_RVALUE(x)` - would not be a constant expression, for obvious reasons. But in the case of reference binding, there is no such conversion.

Comment: Does it depend on the initializer? (E.g. does `int x = rand();` still make `x` a constant expression?)

Comment: @M.M No. (Yes.) A lvalue constant expression merely designates the entity (basically, it's like its address). What it is initialized with is irrelevant, and need not even be known to the compiler (e.g., `extern int x;` is sufficient).