# MSVC 2017 violating static initialization order within single translation unit

Tags: c++, visual-c++, reference, constexpr, static-initialization

MSVC 2017 Community with `-std=c++17` chokes on the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct TC
{
    static TC const values[];
    static TC const& A;
    static TC const& B;
    static TC const& C;

    int const _value;
};

inline constexpr TC const TC::values[]{ { 42 }, { 43 }, { 44 } };
inline constexpr TC const& TC::A{ values[0U] };
inline constexpr TC const& TC::B{ values[1U] };
inline constexpr TC const& TC::C{ values[2U] };

int main(int, char**) noexcept
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << "&A == &values[0]? " << (&TC::A == &TC::values[0U]) << "\n" 
        << "&B == &values[1]? " << (&TC::B == &TC::values[1U]) << "\n"
        << "&C == &values[2]? " << (&TC::C == &TC::values[2U]) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The *expected* output is:

```
&A == &values[0]? true
&B == &values[1]? true
&C == &values[2]? true
```

Which is what both gcc and clang produce, but MSVC gives:

```
&A == &values[0]? true
&B == &values[1]? false
&C == &values[2]? false
```

MSVC does give the correct results if the `_value` member is removed and there is no user-defined constructor.

As all of this is within a single translation unit, my understanding is that this falls under [*Partially-ordered dynamic initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization):

> 2) Partially-ordered dynamic initialization, which applies to all
>   inline variables that are not an implicitly or explicitly instantiated
>   specialization. If a partially-ordered V is defined before ordered or
>   partially-ordered W in every translation unit, the initialization of V
>   is sequenced before the initialization of W (or happens-before, if the
>   program starts a thread)

I cannot use a function to ensure initialization order as I require `constexpr` values **and** `constexpr` references to them.

So the question is, MSVC *is* in violation of the standard* here, correct?

*Of course [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com) isn't "the standard", but I'm assuming that the information there is correctly sourced.

Comment: Since when is it legal to declare an object as non-constexpr then define it as constexpr..?

Comment: Sounds like something to submit as feedback to MS (either under VS' help menu -> submit feedback) or perhaps https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/62/index.html (it used to be connect.microsoft.com but that has apparently been discontinued).

Comment: @ildjarn I can't see anything in the standard outlawing this usage

Comment: @ildjarn [Richard Smith cites the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008861/initializing-a-static-constexpr-from-an-incomplete-type-because-of-a-template-ba/21589173#21589173) - "7.1.5/1 says 'The `constexpr` specifier shall be applied only to the definition of a variable...'" So `constexpr` (apparently) is not needed on the declaration.

Comment: @monkey_05_06 In the "..." of that quote it goes on to list other places where `constexpr` can be applied, such as declarations. Also that quote is from C++11.

Comment: @M.M *can* be or **must** be? Because if it's the latter, then gcc, clang, and MSVC are all in violation of the standard in that respect. Also, this is currently the only way to define a `constexpr` object as a `static` member of its own defining class.

Comment: @M.M I looked over N3797 (which I gather was the draft that was standardized as C++11), and unless the statements in 7.1.5/1 have changed in later standards, then `constexpr` is allowed on the "definition of a variable... **or** the declaration of a static data member of a literal type" (emphasis mine). It does require `constexpr` to match across all function declarations and variable template declarations, but it is explicitly **disallowed** on variable declarations *except* static members of a literal type, where it seems to be optional if there is a separate definition.

Comment: @monkey_05_06 N3337 is the C++11 .  N3797 was between C++11 and C++14 (which is N4140). I think you are misinterpreting that paragraph. (To discuss further post a separate question about that topic)

Comment: @M.M I did post [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50440671/1136311), in which I cite the C++17 standard. Thanks for clarifying which paper I referenced here, but the text is largely still the same in C++17 anyway!

Answer (score 3):

I isolate the same problem to this simpler example:

```
#include <iostream>

int values[3];
constexpr int& v{ values[1] };

int main()
{
    std::cout << &v << ", " << &values[1] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

which, using latest MSVC 2017 Community, gives output of:

```
0119D035, 0119D038
```

The problem does not happen if `constexpr` is removed.

So I think this is a compiler bug with `constexpr` reference initialization.  The reference was initialized to `&values[0]` + 1 byte, not `&values[1]` as it should be.

NB. If anyone is not familiar with `constexpr` reference definitions, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28614655/1505939) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535233/constexpr-reference-to-non-const-object). `constexpr` enforces that the initializer is an object with static storage duration.

Comment: Thanks for that confirmation! I'll give it a couple of days to see if anyone else has anything to add, but otherwise I'll mark this as the accepted answer and cite it in a defect report. Cheers!

Comment: Unsurprisingly, MSVC still chokes initializing from an expression like `&values[0] + 1` or `std::addressof(values[0]) + 1`, but it actually works correctly if we use a bit of type punning on the pointer. `reinterpret_cast` fails (as it should), but both MSVC and gcc still allow `*static_cast<int const*>(static_cast<void const*>(static_cast<char const*>(static_cast<void const*>(&values[0])) + (sizeof(int) * 2)))`, and with that, MSVC actually binds the reference to the right object (as does gcc). clang doesn't allow such nonsense.

Comment: I expanded on your test case [here](https://ideone.com/yTeLdT) (I couldn't find an online compiler for MSVC C++17). GCC gives exactly the expected output, but MSVC 2017 Community shows that every reference is off by exactly `3*n` bytes for the reference to item `IntArray[n]`.

Comment: After a lot of trial and error trying to figure out the code formatting of Microsoft's Developer Community forums (pro-tip: there is none), I opted to just [post a screenshot instead](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/258780/constexpr-reference-to-array-member-has-wrong-addr.html). Their forums also don't (*apparently*) allow hyperlinks, but I referenced the question number for this SO question.