# Is the constexpr specifier required on the declaration of a constexpr static member initialized outside of the class?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr

**C++17 §10.1.5/1** states:

> The `constexpr` specifier shall be applied only to the definition of a
>   variable or variable template or the declaration of a function or
>   function template. A function or static data member declared with the
>   `constexpr` specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable
>   (10.1.6). If any declaration of a function or function template has a
>   `constexpr` specifier, then all its declarations shall contain the
>   `constexpr` specifier.

A similar paragraph has existed in the standard since C++11 (§7.1.5/1), which is cited in [a comment by Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008861/initializing-a-static-constexpr-from-an-incomplete-type-because-of-a-template-ba/21589173#comment35808446_21589173), in which he contends that the C++ Standard does **not** require the `constexpr` specifier to match between the *declaration* and *definition* of a variable. The last statement of the above paragraph **explicitly** requires the `constexpr` specifier to match across *function and function template* declarations, but does **not** mention variable declarations.

**§10.1.5/9** states:

> A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the
>   object as `const`. Such an object shall have literal type and shall be
>   initialized. In any `constexpr` variable declaration, the
>   full-expression of the initialization shall be a constant expression
>   (8.20).

Of course if we have a separate declaration and definition, they will both need to match in `const`ness, regardless of whether the `constexpr` specifiers are required to match.

**§12.2.3.2/2-3** says:

> 2 The declaration of a non-inline static data member in its class
>   definition is not a definition and may be of an incomplete type other
>   than *cv* `void`. The definition for a static data member that is not
>   defined inline in the class definition shall appear in a namespace
>   scope enclosing the member’s class definition. In the definition at
>   namespace scope, the name of the static data member shall be qualified
>   by its class name using the :: operator. The *initializer* expression in
>   the definition of a static data member is in the scope of its class
>   (6.3.7).
>
> 3 If a non-volatile non-inline `const` static data member is of
>   integral or enumeration type... If the member is declared with the
>   `constexpr` specifier, it may be redeclared in namespace scope with no
>   initializer (this usage is deprecated; see D.1). Declarations of other
>   static data members shall not specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer*.

**§D.1/1** reads:

> For compatibility with prior C++ International Standards, a `constexpr`
>   static data member may be redundantly redeclared outside the class
>   with no initializer. This usage is deprecated.

From which we can gather that if the member is *declared* with the `constexpr` specifier, then a namespace scope *definition* is redundant and the *initializer* expression must be paired with the *declaration* and must be omitted from the *definition*/*redeclaration*.

To serve as a complete example, I offer up the case of a static member of its own literal type class (which **cannot** be initialized in-class):

```
struct S
{
    static S const ZERO; // not marked `constexpr`, but still `const`

    constexpr S(int value = {}) : _value{ value } {}

    int const _value;
};

constexpr S S::ZERO{ 0 }; // implicitly `inline` (if C++17) and `const`
```

This interpretation of `constexpr` use with static data members is supported by GCC, Clang, and MSVC, though [I have been told that this is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50402741/msvc-2017-violating-static-initialization-order-within-single-translation-unit?noredirect=1#comment87858532_50402741).

Is it a violation to have non-matching use of the `constexpr` specifier across variable declarations and definitions?

If this is in fact a violation, then it is impossible to correctly define a `constexpr` static data member of its own class, as in-class definitions are prohibited because the type is incomplete and out-of-class definitions are prohibited from including an initializer if the in-class declaration is marked with the `constexpr` specifier.

Comment: Tagged as both "c++11" and "c++17" because the behavior applies to both (except for the implicit inlining of C++17). Standards quotes are cited from C++17 paper N4659.

Comment: Note that in C++17, when a static data member declaration within the class definition uses either `constexpr` or `inline`, the declaration within the class definition is a definition, and any redeclaration outside the class definition is not a definition: [basic.def]/(2.3) and (2.4).

Comment: @aschepler yes, that citation is also relevant, though neither `constexpr` nor `inline` are applied to the code in question. Thanks.

Comment: Related, but about C++11 specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928089/

Comment: @aschepler I have come across several questions (that perhaps should be marked as duplicates) of a similar nature. Most of them have accepted answers that it isn't possible, though as I noted above, GCC, Clang, and MSVC all support this approach.

Comment: @monkey_05_06, what do you mean by "*which cannot be initialized **in-class***"?

Comment: @codekaizer a static member of its own class can only be initialized at namespace scope, because at the time the member is being declared (inside the class definition), the class itself is an incomplete type.

Comment: [Richard Smith commented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928089/static-constexpr-member-of-same-type-as-class-being-defined/12558623#comment17063348_12558623) and cited C++11 §3.5/10, noting that the `constexpr` specifier is **not** part of a variable's type. The `constexpr` specifier does implicitly mean `const`, which is part of the variable's type, but `constexpr` itself is not.

Comment: Sorry if this is clear to others, but doesn't §12.2.3.2 say that it would not be inline, even though `static constexpr` implies inline in c++17?

Comment: @user975989 the portions of §12.2.3.2 I cited above do refer to static data members that aren't inline, but they aren't defining any rules about what is or isn't inline. This does define whether a static data member needs an *initializer* statement at class scope or namespace scope though, which is why I've included it.

Comment: The title seems wrong, in your example the constexpr is NOT required on the definition of ZERO and in fact the question is whether it is optionally allowed or not

Comment: @M.M how exactly do you suppose that "is it optionally allowed" and "is it required" to not be effectively asking the same thing? The code example I provided was provided because that is the **only** way to make it work and compile *and* it *actually* works and compiles on GCC, Clang, and MSVC. There is no alternative code example that would be useful for anything other than illustrating that "this code **doesn't** actually work".

Comment: @monkey0506 [example](https://godbolt.org/g/z4rHa3) , that was the normal way of doing things until recently. It is definitely not "required" to use `constexpr`.  The discussion on the other question was about whether the addition of `constexpr` made the code illegal

Comment: @M.M you can attribute whatever meaning you want to my words, but both questions were raised by me, specifically to the end of making a `constexpr` static data member of its containing class. I never asked whether `constexpr` was required to define a static data member, so please leave your strawmen out of this discussion. There was never any "addition of `constexpr`", `constexpr` members were precisely the topic at hand.

Comment: @M.M I edited the title since you seemingly took it as ambiguous or otherwise unclear. The question was always about `constexpr` static data members.

Comment: What "strawmen" are you talking about? I'm just trying to understand your question

Comment: The argument you've made against my post was never relevant to the question I asked. I've updated the title, so there is absolutely no way that it could reasonably be seen as unclear or ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to read this:

```
static S const ZERO; // not marked `constexpr`, but still `const`
```

`S::ZERO` will never change its value during run-time due to `const`.

However:

```
constexpr S S::ZERO{ 0 }; // implicitly `inline` (if C++17) and `const`
```

`Constant Evaluation` is done for `S::ZERO` which will have constant integral value `0` for `_value`. 
This invokes your `constexpr constructor`:

```
constexpr S(int value = {}) : _value{ value } {}
```

As per [basic.start.static](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start.static#2) - *Constant Initialization*:

> A *constant initializer* for a variable or temporary object `o` is an
>   initializer whose full-expression is a *constant expression*, except
>   that if `o` is an object, such an initializer may also invoke
>   *constexpr constructors* for `o` and its subobjects even if those objects are of non-literal class types.

AND [expr.const/8.7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const#8.7) - *Constant Evaluation*:

> a variable whose name appears as a potentially constant evaluated
>   expression that is either a *constexpr variable* or is of non-volatile
>   const-qualified integral type or of reference type.

Therefore:

> Is it a violation to have non-matching use of the constexpr specifier
>   across variable declarations and definitions?

I believe your code is fine.

Comment: "I believe your code is fine." Thanks, I believe so too. This question was mainly to open up the dialogue of whether the standards have a glaring defect by not requiring these declarations and definitions to match in `constexpr` usage. I don't believe the standards are defective (in this respect), but others do seem to believe they are.